# regarding the third parameter of cv2.fillpoly

Tags: image-processing, opencv3.0, opencv, python

I once saw the following code segment of using `cv2.fillpoly`. The third parameter should correspond to color, but here it use `i+1`, what does it mean here?

```
# convert to pixel mask (method 1)
mask_1 = np.zeros(shape)
for i in range(len(polys)):
    cv2.fillPoly(mask_1, polys[i], i+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga8c69b68fab5f25e2223b6496aa60dad5) there are two ctors for `fillPoly`:

- 1. The third parameter is `npts`

> void cv::fillPoly (InputOutputArray img, const Point** pts, const int * npts, ...)

- 2. The third parameter is `color`

> void cv::fillPoly(InputOutputArray img, InputArrayOfArrays pts, const Scalar & color, ...)

From what I understand, the number of points also refers to the color. If we look at an [example](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89415/cv2.fillPoly):

```py
#filling pixels inside the polygon defined by "vertices" with the fill color    
cv2.fillPoly(mask, vertices, 255)
```

In your example, different color values were given starting from `1-len(poly)+1`

As `i` increases the color turns from black to white (`1` black, `255` white)

Though I don't know whether it exceeds 255.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah third parameter is for color (`(b,g,r)` format ) but it also accepts integer. The default color is red and when only integer is given in argument, it considers it as a shade of red. 0 is black. 1 to 255 are shades of red. Numbers beyond 255 are clipped to 255

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

contours = np.array( [ [50,50], [50,150], [150, 150], [150,50] ] )
img = np.zeros( (200,200,3),dtype=np.uint8 ) 
cv2.fillPoly(img, pts =[contours], color=(100))
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

But when you give 200

```
contours = np.array( [ [50,50], [50,150], [150, 150], [150,50] ] )
img = np.zeros( (200,200,3),dtype=np.uint8 ) 
cv2.fillPoly(img, pts =[contours], color=(200))
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]